# Rails not using generated CSS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I've got a Rails 3.1 application. I generate a Controller, just to show what's happening:

```
$ rails generate controller Rocks index show edit
      create  app/controllers/rocks_controller.rb
       route  get "rocks/edit"
       route  get "rocks/show"
       route  get "rocks/index"
      invoke  haml
      create    app/views/rocks
      create    app/views/rocks/index.html.haml
      create    app/views/rocks/show.html.haml
      create    app/views/rocks/edit.html.haml
      invoke  rspec
      create    spec/controllers/rocks_controller_spec.rb
      create    spec/views/rocks
      create    spec/views/rocks/index.html.haml_spec.rb
      create    spec/views/rocks/show.html.haml_spec.rb
      create    spec/views/rocks/edit.html.haml_spec.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/rocks_helper.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/helpers/rocks_helper_spec.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/rocks.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/rocks.css.scss
```

Great. Looking good. Generated `app/assets/stylesheets/rocks.css.scss`. Just what I wanted.

Now, navigating to `http://localhost:3000/rocks/index`, I examine the source and see:

```
  <head> 
    ...
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/assets/rocks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    ...
  </head>
```

rocks.css is missing, and I have no idea why. Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `application.css` should have this lines:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

the most important:

```
*= require_tree .
```

Then `rocks.css` should be included by the application.css, that's an advantage using `assets`

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks! I think you meant application.css though.

Comment: Rails is getting more and more maddening :) but ♪ ♫I'm loving it♪ ♫

Comment: One question: Is it possible to only include application.css and the relevant controller CSS file? require_tree adds all CSS files in.

Comment: @Mike Sure you can, you can remove that line `require_tree .` from the manifest file and specify individual files to load and compile into application.css, take a look here ~> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives